# Outlook 2013 Sending E-mail As Another User

Tags: email, permissions, microsoft-outlook-2013

How would one send an email as another user using Outlook 2013 without "On Behalf of" appearing in the message? The user has delegate access to the other user's account and has the appropriate permissions to send e-mails, respond to calendar events, and other admin assistant type permissions. Does the "on behalf message" depend on the permissions set in the delegate access or is as easy as clicking on the other user's inbox and crafting a new email? So far the "From" field in message creation has been using and is showing "on behalf of", rather than actually sending the email as the other user.

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure the server has to be configured to support something like this.  The sender email is text it can be anything who actually sends it is registered by the server which is determined by the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience "on behalf of" is something that email clients show based on difference between `From` and `Sender` / `Return-Path` headers in the email. You can see those headers in Outlook if you right-click on a message in mailbox and select `Message Options` (in the pop-up dialog look under `Internet headers`).

The only ways to elimate the difference between those headers is either to send the mail using the other user's account or have your SMTP (outbound email) server modify the headers for you before sending the message outside of your network. Since email headers are not really enforced to be truthful (the reason behind why spamming is so wild and widely spread business), it is technically quite easy to forge those two headers but nevertheless it's likely that no common desktop GUI email application will allow the user to modify them. Pine / Alpine allow doing all that kind of funky stuff, though, so it would be wrong for me to say not any email client would allow that.

**Edit:** Also, as Ramhound pointed out, the mail server might refuse to send email if the (forged) headers created a conflict between the authenticated user (=you) and the user appearing as the sender (since that could indicate a security breach and/or sending spam and in general would most likely be a violation against the security policy applicable to email users).